# Submit Button runs the Create method, not Logon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, haml

We implemented a simple login method for our Ruby on Rails project, we have a button on the page to submit for the login information that the user will enter, but instead of pointing to our login method, the submit button runs our create method and tries to create another user.

```
def login
  username = params[:username]
  password = params[:password]
  if(username == NIL || password == NIL)
    loginfailed
  else
    comparisonUser = User.where("username = ?", username)
    if(comparisonUser == NIL)
      loginfailed
    else
      comparisonPassword = comparisonUser.password
      if(comparisonPassword == password)
       flash[:notice] = "Login Successful"
         @user = comparisonUser
      else 
        loginfailed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the Create method:

```
def create
  @user = User.create!(params[:user])
  flash[:notice] = "User,  #{@user.username} was successfully created."
  redirect_to questions_path
end
```

and the code for the login button on the web page:

```
            =  form_tag users_path do
              =  label :userlogin, :username, 'Username'
              =  text_field :userlogin, :username
              %br/
              =  label :userlogin, :password, 'Password'
              =  text_field :userlogin, :password
              %br/
              = submit_tag 'Login', :id => 'Login'
```

I probably need to add some more information to the submit_tag, but im not sure what to do.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting to the users_path, which is typically the create action (unless you've modified the route).

Instead of `form_tag users_path` you need to reference the appropriate route.

Comment: How would I add a route that points directly to the login method? Im very new to ruby, so im sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: The full guide is at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, but you probably want something like:

`match "/login" => "users#login", :as => 'login'`

Then you can reference `login_path`

Comment: Im curious, when I have been playing around with different match statements it wants me to make another view, would this be the only way to do it or can I keep the same view I have an just point it directly at the method?

Comment: login is a controller action; you need to either have a corresponding view, render a different view, or redirect to a different url. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render has info on rendering something different, and then the following section covers redirect_to